# Transforming back and forth between reference frames using orthogonal transformation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonal-matrices

The transformation of a covariance matrix $C$ from reference frame 1 to reference frame 2 is described as

\begin{equation}
C_2 = R_{12}C_1R_{12}^T
\end{equation}

using the (orthogonal) transformation matrix $R_{12}$, where the superscript $T$ denotes the transpose. In this case, I know what $C_2$ is and I want to find $C_1$. How do I use these transformation matrices in order to get $C_1$?

Comment: Multiply by inverses on both sides and use the fact that for an orthogonal matrix $R^T=R^{-1}$.

Comment: So how does that look like mathematically? I am not sure on the notation... Would the equation then be $C_1$ = $R_{12}^TC_2R_{12}$?

Comment: Just so. I’ll write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate $C_1$ by multiplying by the appropriate inverses on both sides: $$C_1 = R_{12}^{-1}C_2R_{12}^{-T}$$ and then, since $R_{12}$ is orthogonal so that $R_{12}^{-1}=R_{12}^T$, $$C_1 = R_{12}^TC_2R_{12}.$$